# LCD display interfaced with Arduino Uno not displaying values

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, lcd

I am a beginner on Arduino. I have a project that I will only be using: a heart rate sensor whose values I am displaying on an LCD display. The code compiles and uploads once I set my project up, but the value doesn't appear on my LCD screen.

```cpp
#include<LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8);
int HBSensor = 4;
int HBCount = 0;
int HBCheck = 0;
int TimeinSec = 0;
int HBperMin = 0;
int HBStart = 2;
int HBStartCheck = 0;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(20, 4);
  pinMode(HBSensor, INPUT);//heartbeat sensor
  pinMode(HBStart, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Timer1.initialize(800000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(timerIsr);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Current HB: ");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Time in Sec :");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 2);
  lcd.print("HB per Min :0.0");
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(HBStart) == LOW) {
    lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
    lcd.print("HB Counting ..");
    HBStartCheck = 1;
  }
  if (HBStartCheck == 1) {
    if ((digitalRead(HBSensor) == HIGH) && (HBCheck == 0)) {
      HBCount = HBCount + 1;
      HBCheck=1;
      lcd.setCursor(14, 0);
      lcd.print(HBCount);
      lcd.print(" ");
    }
    if ((digitalRead(HBSensor) == LOW) && (HBCheck == 1)) {
      HBCheck=0;
    }
    if (TimeinSec == 10) {
      HBperMin=HBCount * 6;
      HBStartCheck=0;
      lcd.setCursor(14, 2);
      lcd.print(HBperMin);
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.setCursor(0, 3);
      lcd.print("Press Button again.");
      HBCount = 0;
      TimeinSec = 0;
    }
  }
}

void timerIsr() {
  if (HBStartCheck == 1) {
    TimeinSec = TimeinSec + 1;
    lcd.setCursor(14, 1);
    lcd.print(TimeinSec);
    lcd.print("");
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't use capslock. Thats the equivalent of shouting at us and makes the text difficult to read.

Comment: Is this still only in the proteus simulation, or do you now use real hardware? And have you tried following the advice from the comments of your other question? Like declaring variables, that are used inside an ISR, as `volatile`?

Comment: No i only using proteus simulation, this code is for hardware i tried the use it in proteus , ( Like declaring variables, that are used inside an ISR, as volatile? ) No sir i am a very beginner can you show me how please??and thank you

Comment: You're doing too much inside the ISR so it takes too much time. Also, the `HBStartCheck` and `TimeinSec` variables are changed inside the ISR but not declared `volatile` so the rest of your code might not see any changes to these variables. change the `int HBStartCheck = 0;` and `int TimeinSec = 0` at the start of your code into `volatile int HBStartCheck;` and `volatile int TimeinSec;`. Also move the `lcd.setCursor()` and `lcd.print()` out of the ISR and do this inside of `loop ()`.

Comment: i remove ` TimeinSec=TimeinSec+1;
    lcd.setCursor(14,1);
    lcd.print(TimeinSec);
    lcd.print("");` in the loop and add volatile in TimeinSec = 0 and HBStartCheck = 0 but still doesn't work

Comment: does the oscilloscope show a signal on channel B?

Comment: Did you configure the sensor with a heartbeat signal (from a hex file)? I ask because in the first question, you provide osci printouts and they were flat. So your sensor has no output.

Comment: I think that you may be not paying attention to details ... in your previous question, you connected a battery backward ... in this question, you connected to one pin and configured the sketch for another pin